# Devise Required Params Not Enforced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've added the first_name, last_name and username fields to my user table and I want to ensure they are set when a user signs up. After some searching it seems the common consensus on how to do this is to extend the registrations controller and use the #permit method to add the params.

This can be seen in https://gist.github.com/jamesrwhite/6a53cccd9284fb3be9f8.

The problem is I can still sign up and leave the first_name, last_name and username fields empty and no errors are shown. I've tried multiple different ways of doing this but none seem to work. I'm using Rails 4.1.1 and Devise 3.2.4.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have missed validation line for 3 fields in your User Model. Could you please try that too.

Comment: Ah of course, I added `validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :username` and now it works, I thought devise might have done that for me. Thanks!